# How to read text file into an array, java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, netbeans, readfile

How can I read a text file into the waitingRoom array? I need to also be able to use this file to add and remove passengers? Can anyone help x

```
package trainstation;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrainStation 
{

    static int WAITING_ROOM_CAPACITY = 30;

    private static Passenger[] waitingRoom = new Passenger[WAITING_ROOM_CAPACITY];
    private static PassengerQueue trainQueue = new PassengerQueue();


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+read+text+file+into+an+array%2C+java%3F) for the title of your question? I bet that would give you lots of good articles to help you get started. --- Besides, how did you expect us to help when we don't know the file format or the class you need to read the file into?

Comment: I have found videos showing how to read a text file into an array but none of them work with my code, so I thought my posting my array someone might be able to help, I am new to coding, what information would you need from my code in order to help?

Comment: At a minimum, the Passenger class and the format of the text file.

Comment: the format of the text file includes 30 first names and surnames in one long column, the passenger class is public

Comment: @taliapiscitelli **Edit** the question and clarify it. Don't clarify in a comment. Show example of the data. As for the class being public, does that mean we can see it somewhere on the web, being available to the public? Or did you mean that your own locally-maintained class has the `public` keyword, which is of no relevance to us seeing what it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
File myObj = new File("filename.txt");
Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);

while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {

  String data = myReader.nextLine();  // The data of the txt file will depends on the format you wanted.
  System.out.println(data); // Or you can append data to an array ...

}
```

Or if your txt file data format is something like this

Name  | Lastname  | 1
Name1 | Lastname1 | 2

Then you have to split each line of data in your txt file by a delimeter..

```
File myObj = new File("filename.txt");
Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);

while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {

  String[] data = (myReader.nextLine()).split(" | "); // It is already an array
  System.out.println(data); // Or you can append data to an array ...

}
```